# Running a Small 64bit Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, 64-bit, cloud

I'm playing with [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), and I've got a 64bit AMI, but when I launch it, the 'Instance Type' only has 'Large', 'Extra Large' and 'High-CPU Extra Large', no 'Small' which the [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing) lists as the default and the cheapest.

Is it cause I'm using 64bit? Can you run a small EC2 instance on 64bit AMI?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Today Amazon released the news that they support 64-bit for m1.small instances, as well as the new m1.medium instances.
>
> Read all about it:
>
> http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/ec2-updates-new-instance-64-bit-bit-ubiquity-ssh-client.html

<strike>No, the small instances are 32-bit only while the large/extra large instances are 64-bit, so you need to use either the large, extra-large or high-CPU extra-large instances for a 64-bit system.</strike>

See the [EC2 instance type list](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#instance) for more details on the different types.

Comment: This is true for the smalls. However, you CAN run a 32-bit OS image on a med/large/xl instance.

Comment: Additionally, EC2 now also has a micro instance size that can run a 64 bit AMI

Comment: So, as of now, if you want 2008 R2 reserved for 3 years, you can either get 613MB RAM for $30/year, or 7.5GB RAM for $470/year. Where's the inbetween option?...

Comment: @user5336; how do you run a 32-bit in a large instance?  The UI doesn't seem to allow it.

Comment: Since yesterday, you can launch 64bit AMIs in every instance type http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/ec2-updates-new-instance-64-bit-bit-ubiquity-ssh-client.html

Answer (score 6):

Today Amazon released the news that they support 64-bit for m1.small instances, as well as the new m1.medium instances.

Read all about it:

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/ec2-updates-new-instance-64-bit-bit-ubiquity-ssh-client.html

Answer (score 3):

Amazon as of today (8th March 2012) supports 64bit small and medium instances. It was first acknowledged by Amazon at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=325209&#325183

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can't run a small instance as 64-bit. That could change; if you look at the instance types available for Amazon's just-announced [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/#highlights) service, they're offering an instance type that's the equivalent of a small 64-bit node. I wouldn't be surprised to see it made generally available to EC2 in the future.

Comment: Looks like it's here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=325209&#325183